# How to transfer facial mocap from Blendartrack?

Tags: mesh, bones, drivers, motion-capture

I’m loving the results I get from Blendartrack for facial mocap but the mesh is baked. I really need to get that motion to a full 3d character with the face of the person I scanned. I’ve been using Blender for almost a year now but never mounted anything quite this complex. I need help!

Comment: What have you tried, and what isn't working?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.